# how to send parameters to jquery plugin function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to pass values to jquery plugin function.

This is my plugin:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.myplugin = function(name,value) {
        alert(name + " , " + value )
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

And this is my call:

```
$('#wrapper').myplugin({name:'test',value:'big_test'});
```

I can't receive any data in my plugin. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you are sending data as object then receive it as object and change your plugin code like

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(data) {
        alert(data.name + " , " + data.value )
    };
```

**Note**:Don't forget to return $(this) object in order to mantain chain ability of jQuery

Comment: thank you...it was right in front of me and I didn't realize it :)

Comment: should I return `this` or `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following pattern:

```
    $.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, options);

        alert(settings.name + " , " + settings.value);
    };
```